# Can't connect to Joomla administration page after Windows10 update

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, session

I'm using Joomla version 3.9.6. I encountered a problem just after a windows update. The error displayed is:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp) in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla3.96\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php on line 260
>   Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Comment: To make this page higher quality for future researchers and search engines, we ask that you never post screenshots of pure text.  It is infinitely better to just copy-paste the text (from the address bar and the page content) into your question.  Please edit your question.  p.s. "updation" is not an English word.  Please register your new JSE account and take the [tour].

Comment: I wonder how your permissions look.  Do you have write permissions on the directory?  Generally, I'd say you should get the ownership right and permissions working in your gavor, but I don't like to post guesses as answers. Please edit your question with these vutal details.  (I failed to capitalize windows in your question -- please fix that too when you update.)